# How to find minimal set of operations to meet requirements

Tags: java, algorithm

I think it's easier, if I show my code first.

```
/* Machine that can add and remove pools to its stack */
public class Machine {
  private final int toolQuantity = 5;
  public boolean addTool(Tool t)    { return true; }
  public boolean removeTool(Tool t) { return true; }
  public boolean processJob(Job j)  { return true; }
}

/* Tool that is needed to process jobs */
class Tool {
}

/* Job that needs specific tools to be processed on machine */
class Job {
  private final List<Tool> needs = Collections.emptyList();
}

interface Command { public void execute(); }

class AddTool implements Command {
  private Machine m;
  private Tool t;
  @Override
  public void execute() { }
  }

class RemoveTool implements Command {
  private Machine m;
  private Tool t;
  @Override
  public void execute() { }
}
```

<sup>Simplyfied code. Aim was just to communicate the idea</sup>

So, I have a machine which processes jobs. Jobs need tools (and the tools have an unlimited lifetime). My aim is to find a minimal list of jobs and commands (i. e. instances of `AddTool` and `RemoveTool` so that: `{"AddTool(x), "job1", AddTool(y), "job2"}`), so that a given **fixed** list of jobs can be processed. Tools that are not needed by a job, can remain on the machine (as long as there is enough place left of course).

---

I have two approaches:

- **SIMPLE**

Collect requierements from job to job. Since this approach only considers job `i` and job `i + 1`. It may not be optimal in cases where machine unloads a tool not needed by job `i + 1` but needed by job `i + 2`. That's an unnecessary cycle of removing and adding (given there was the possibility to remove another not needed tool).

- **HEURISTIC**

Use an heuristic algorith, e. g. simulated annealing, that minimizes the number of commands used.

I would prefer to use a straight forward aproach. But I can't think of another and I guess the simple approach is too unefficient.

So how can I solve my problem? How can it be classified in terms of computer science? I would also appreciate general solutions to these kind of problems that don't specificly handle jobs, machines and tools.

Comment: While an interesting problem, I think it's outside the scope of Stackoverflow - perhaps http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ or http://cs.stackexchange.com/ would be better?

Comment: Hmm, I think I could leave out the part of the question that's about 'classifying the problem in terms of CS'. But I still think it fits the site.

Comment: Considering there's a remove tool command, it would be helpful to add the constraint that for a job to be completed there must be all the tools it requires and no other tools.

If there is no such constraint, you'd just need to find the set of tools needed for all jobs and add them.

Comment: No there is no such constraint. The problem is a machine just has place for a certain amount of tools. I modeled that in `toolQuantity`, unused tools can remain on the machine. But the needed tools **must** be on the machine.

Comment: Just to clarify, the order of the jobs is not decided, so by changing the order you affect the number of actions performed, correct? Is the first job decided or it can be any job in the list?

Comment: @mwjohnson Yes, you're 100% right. But the order of jobs is fixed. I determined it in a previous step. Look at the comment I gave to kutschkem's answer. This question is only about finding the optimal list of operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [hamiltonian path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem), or maybe a [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)(if you modify the problem a little bit). Each job needs a certain amount of tools, and you can determine how many commands are needed to get from one job to the other. You want a path through that graph that minimizes the "distance" in terms of additions/removals and visits all nodes/jobs.

Comment: Finding the optimal sequence of jobs already was a TSP (or hamaltonian path problem... I think TSP is an instance of it). Where I used a heuristic that did compute the 'distance' between jobs. I thought deriving the needed operations could be easier since the list of jobs is already fixed... :/ Thx!

Comment: Since your answer is an acutal solution, I will accept it. But I first want to wait for other approaches, because I originally wanted to avoid using heuristic approaches (and NP-hard problems).

Comment: @mike computing the distance between the jobs seems like a planning problem to me. For example, look up http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STRIPS . This describes the problem, and you should be able to find algorithms to solve such a problem.